# How to use Crashlytics without using Fabric in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Is it possible to use Crashlytics without installing Fabric?
Right now, I have used Crashlytics by using Fabric.

References:
https://try.crashlytics.com/
https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

But now I want to use Crashlytics without using Fabric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to use Crashlytics without installing Fabric?

NO. **Crashlytics** is under the **Fabric** framework.

Comment: Thank you, but as we know **Fabric** framework having four functionality : [Crashlytics, Twitter, Digits, MoPub] and I only want to use Crashlytics, so how can I remove others?

Comment: Just do #import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h> ... And of course the three frameworks will not be used. Don't worry, as I've learned in Harvard's lecture in iOS - I watched it online, the #import is smart enough to know what you just need. While the #include in C programming language will literally include all your stuff to your program.

Comment: Ok cool. Thank you so much for the detailed info.

If you have got any information please share it.

Comment: Welcome, Mradul. You might want to select my answer as your 'answer' if you got what you needed.

Comment: @prettyitgirl.com Hi ,I have to start the integartion of Crashlytics in my app now. So you mean ,now no crashlytics as separate entity but everything is included in fabric framework. The only solution is to integrate Fabric and use?Is my underatanding correct. My app should support iOS 8 and above.

Comment: @SMS - Integrating Crashlytics will need you to import two frameworks. The Fabric and the Crashlytics. So, you will have to have #import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h> Just follow the easy step-by-step instruction in your Fabric Desktop App, and everything will be fine.

Comment: It does not appear to be needed at this point. Fabric is a hassle and I hope to never hear about it again. Why can't FirebaseCrash just push their logs over?